# MS Access wont let me use parameter more than once in another context

Tags: ms-access, parameters, report, label

This code is used in a label for MS Access report. However the parameter will repeat, I would like to use in the report the parameter twice like a variable to call again and pass in the context of the function, for both the month and year to print in text exactly when. Is there a way to use a parameter multiple times so you enter it once instead like a variable declaration which happens once?
I use a record source from another query, the query parameter also pops up with the label parameters, simply I need to refactor all of these into one of each.

`=[Reports]![List_Select by Type and Date]![Enter type to filter: (1, A, B, C, D, E)] & ",  List of " & MonthName(Month(([Reports]![List_Select by Type and Date]![Enter cutoff date:]))) & ", " & Year([Reports]![List_Select by Type and Date]![Enter cutoff date:]`)))

Comment: If the same parameter is used in an underlying query, output it as a calculated field in the underlying query and then it will be available to your report.

Comment: How would you go about outputting the parameter as a calculated field?

Comment: SELECT X,Y,Z, [Enter type to filter: (1, A, B, C, D, E)] AS MyFilterValue FROM AnotherQuery WHERE X = [Enter type to filter: (1, A, B, C, D, E)]

Comment: I figure that must be done in SQL view on the original query. then I should be able to ref x for example in the report?

Comment: yes. I may post some other methods if I have time.